# Python: Plotting equation with the Dirac Delta function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to plot the expected diffraction pattern from a sharp razor which has a formula of:

$$ I(p) = \frac 14 \delta^2(p) + \frac {1}{4\pi^2p^2}$$
where $p = \frac {\sin\theta}{\lambda}$

I initially want to just make a simple list of x values and feed them into the equation to get y values and plot those, like so:

```
x = [theta for theta in range(-90,90)]

y = [I(theta) for theta in x]

plt.plot(x,y)
```

However, I'm not sure how to write $I(\theta)$ because I don't know how to write a dirac delta function in python. How would one graph this function?

Comment: Do you only need to plot the I function? Or are there downstream things you need to use your y variable for besides plotting?  I'd suggest representing the delta functions with vertical arrows (it's how I've always seen the Dirac delta).

Answer (score 0):

## Use the scipy library function

## in this example

import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
number_points =100
location_of_impulse= 60
it_theta=signal.unit_impulse(number_points ,location_of_impulse)

## you'll have to do your own scaling

By the the way the following is a direct copy from the SCIPY sit and may be more illuminating
..........................................................................

import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
imp = signal.unit_impulse(100, 40)
b, a = signal.butter(4, 0.2)
response = signal.lfilter(b, a, imp)

plt.plot(np.arange(-50, 50), imp)
plt.plot(np.arange(-50, 50), response)
plt.margins(0.1, 0.1)
plt.xlabel('Time [samples]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.grid(True)

'